# jQuery add attribute to span and alert when added

Tags: jquery, html

I have html table like below:

```
<table id="list" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class='thread selected'>
    <td class='subject'>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td class='flags'>
    <span class='attach'></span>
    <span class='flag'>
    <span class='flag'></span>
    </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='thread'>
    <td class='subject'>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td class='flags'>
    <span class='attach'></span>
    <span class='flag'>
    </span>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If a user select a row I want to add dynamically `title='With flag'`in last span like

```
<span class='flag' title='With flag'></span>
</span>
```

and want to `alert('title added');` using if statement.

How can I achive this using jQuery

Comment: on what event do you want to add the span title. what do you mean by select? click?

Comment: on click event.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(".thread").click(function() {
    $(".flag").attr("title","With flag");
    alert("title added"); 
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".thread").click(function() {
   $(this).find(".flag").attr("title","With flag");
   alert("title added"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
$('#list').on("click", '.thread tr', function(){
    $(".flag").attr("title","With flag");
   alert("title added");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find last td using `last-child` and `span` with class `flag` and add your attribute.

```js
$(".thread").click(function() {
   $(this).find('td:last-child span.flag').attr("title","With flag");
   alert("title added"); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="list" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class='thread selected'>
    <td class='subject'>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td class='flags'>
    <span class='attach'></span>
    <span class='flag'>
    <span class='flag'></span>
    </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='thread'>
    <td class='subject'>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td class='flags'>
    <span class='attach'></span>
    <span class='flag'>
    </span>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```